# How to assign to an object entry that was indexed using a variable cast to a keyof type

Tags: typescript

I have a key-value interface definition like:

```js
interface AnInterface {
  foo?: number;
  bar?: string;
  baz?: boolean;
}
```

I want to write functions such as this one below where I can modify a value given a key. I've written this example:

```js
type AnInterfaceKeyVal<K extends keyof AnInterface = keyof AnInterface> = {
  [P in K]: {
    property: P;
    val: AnInterface[P];
  };
}[K];

function modifyObjectItem(
  objectToModify: AnInterface,
  keyVal: AnInterfaceKeyVal<keyof AnInterface>
) {
  const output = { ...objectToModify };
  switch (typeof keyVal.val) {
    case 'string':
      output[keyVal.property] = keyVal.val;
      break;
    case 'number':
      output[keyVal.property] = keyVal.val;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return output;
}
```

I'm confused why, in this example, I get a TS2322 error (e.g. "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'") on the line where I do the assignment (`output[keyVal.property] = keyVal.val`).

Similarly if I add a line: `output['bar' as keyof AnInterface] = 'new value'` to the function, that doesn't work, and gives the same error.

Why would the values `output[keyVal.property]` and `output['bar' as keyof AnInterface]` have type `undefined` and not `string | number | boolean | undefined`? I think this is the reason why I get this error.

I'm additionally confused because if I assign `output[keyVal.property]` to a new variable, that variable can be assigned the value of `keyVal.val`. i.e. this function (which doesn't work for the intended purpose) doesn't show the error:

```
function modifyObjectItem(
  objectToModify: AnInterface,
  keyVal: AnInterfaceKeyVal<keyof AnInterface>
) {
  const output = { ...objectToModify };
  switch (typeof keyVal.val) {
    case 'string':
      {
        let a = output[keyVal.property];
        a = keyVal.val;
      }
      break;
    case 'number':
      {
        let b = output[keyVal.property];
        b = keyVal.val;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return output;
}
```

If I add an index signature `[key: string]: number | string | boolean | undefined` to the interface definition the TS2322 errors go away. This is a potential solution but I'd prefer to only be able to index the interface using the known keys rather than a string. I think that if I add the index signature, I can index with any string, and potentially get errors by indexing with the wrong string.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with your code that you might not even be asking about.  For example, your definition allows you to call `modifyObjectItem({}, { property: "foo", val: "OOPS" })` because `AnInterfaceKeyVal<keyof AnInterface>` allows both `property` and `val` to take on any of their possible values.  Could you fix that (say, by making `AnInterfaceKeyVal` distributive across its input type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wep7BW)) so we can focus on the issue?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I modified the question following your example.

Comment: Great.  So now the primary issue is that checking `typeof keyVal.val` only acts as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) on `keyVal.val` does not act as a type guard on `keyVal` itself.  The only way checking a property narrows the type of its parent object is if that parent object's type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and the property is its discriminant.  So you could refactor to [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrnMzN), maybe

Comment: Does that meet your needs, or is there a reason why you need to check the type of `val` instead of the value of `property`?  If it meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz thanks again, that works as a solution for this example. In my real application the interface has more entries than the 3 in the example. Usually the object properties of the same type will have the same implementation in the switch case, which is why I used the `typeof keyVal.val` as the thing to switch on. I can achieve the same by doing as you suggested and having fall-throughs (e.g. [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbBRPm)). An issue is that if a new element is added to the interface the switch has to be updated even if the logic for that elements type is already established.

Comment: Hmm, kind of wish the motivating example didn't have an obvious "use the discriminant" option, but okay.  Let's say that, for whatever reason, we need to check `typeof keyVal.val` instead of `keyVal.property` directly.  In that case you could build your own custom type guard function and use it (as long as you're okay with a series of `if`/`else` instead of `switch`/`case`) to narrow `keyVal`.  It might look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbBOEm).  If that meets your needs better I could write up an answer.  Let me know how you'd like me to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz I'm still trying to get my head around the second half of that type predicate but that does work better for me, thanks again. I'll accept that answer if you write it up. I can edit the example in the question as well if you think that helps make a better question & answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AnInterfaceKeyVal` type is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) equivalent to:

```
type AnInterfaceKeyVal = {
    property: "foo";
    val: number | undefined;
} | {
    property: "bar";
    val: string | undefined;
} | {
    property: "baz";
    val: boolean | undefined;
};
```

Inside `modifyObjectItem()`, you are attempting to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of `keyVal` from `AnInterfaceKeyVal`, by testing `typeof keyVal.val`.  Unfortunately, narrowing in TypeScript does not work this way.

Currently the only way you can check a property of a union-typed object and have it narrow the type of the object is if you are checking a *discriminant* property of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type.  Well, `AnInterfaceKeyVal` *is* a discriminated union, but `val` is not a discriminant property.  Discriminant properties must be [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or unions of such literals.  The types `number` and `string` don't count.  You *could* check the `property` property, since those are string literals `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"baz"`.  But you don't want to have to do that.

---

Since TypeScript doesn't do this for you, you need to work around it.  One way to proceed is to encapsulate this logic into a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  Let's generalize your check to something like `hasPropOfType(obj, key, type)` that, if it returns `true`, narrows the apparent type of `obj` to something that has a property at the key `key` and where `typeof obj[key] === type`.  You'd use it like this:

```
function modifyObjectItem(
    objectToModify: AnInterface,
    keyVal: AnInterfaceKeyVal<keyof AnInterface>
) {
    const output = { ...objectToModify };
    if (hasPropOfType(keyVal, "val", "string")) {
        output[keyVal.property] = keyVal.val; // okay
    } else if (hasPropOfType(keyVal, "val", "number")) {
        output[keyVal.property] = keyVal.val; // okay
    }
    return output;
}
```

This could be streamlined a bit (you could hardcode `"val"`), but the general flow would look like this.  You'd need to change `switch`/`case` to `if`/`else` because user-defined type guard functions return `boolean`.

---

So, how could we define `hasPropOfType()`?  Here's one way:

```
interface TypeofMap {
    string: string,
    number: number,
    bigint: bigint,
    symbol: symbol,
    boolean: boolean,
    undefined: undefined,
    object: object | null
    function: Function
}

function hasPropOfType<
    O extends object,
    K extends keyof O,
    T extends keyof TypeofMap>(
        obj: O, key: K, type: T
    ): obj is Record<K, TypeofMap[T]> &
    (O extends any ? TypeofMap[T] extends O[K] ? O : never : never) {
    return typeof obj[key] === type;
}
```

That's quite a handful, but let's go over it.  The `TypeofMap` type is a mapping from the outputs of `typeof x` at runtime to the TypeScript type of `x`.  If you write `typeof x === "string"`, then we know `x` should be of type `string`, etc.  `typeof x === "object"` is a little weird because the TS type for that is `object | null`, but whatever.

The implementation of `hasPropOfType()` is just `return typeof obj[key] === type`, which should be self-explanatory.  But the crazy part is the type guarded by the type predicate.  *Conceptually* you'd want something like `obj is Extract<O, Record<K, TypeofMap[T]>>`... if `O` is a union then you want to filter it to just those members whose value at key `K` is of type `TypeofMap[T]`.

Unfortunately it's not that simple.  You want to filter `O` to those members whose value at key `K` is *a supertype of* `TypeofMap[T]`; if it has a member of type `unknown` you can't eliminate it.  Hence `(O extends any ? TypeofMap[T] extends O[K] ? O : never : never)`, which [distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over `O`, and keeps only those members where `O[K]` is a supertype of `TypeofMap[T]`.

And finally we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `Record<K, TypeofMap[T]>`, because we also know that the type of `obj[key]` is actually `TypeofMap[T]`.  Without it, we'd narrow `obj` from `AnInterfaceKeyVal` to, say, `{property: "foo", val: number | undefined}`, but we know that `val` is not `undefined` if `typeof obj[k]==="number"`.  So we narrow to `{val: number} & {property: "foo", val: number | undefined}`, which is equivalent to `{property: "foo", val: number}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIgJLmvJyDeAUMicjAPbkD8AXMiAK4C2ARtANzGktxS3IBnMFFABzTqWQ8AXvxaUANhDghOAX0KEwATwAOKdFkixEEANIRtANTgKAPGeQQAHpBAATAcgDWl8jDRMbBM8AF4fPwDDYNwIAD5kcPxkAG0ABWRQZDMAXToiSV0ocn0oHTo0iVIAN1s6aONY9Jz1ZDUU3M0dfWQAUQBHBmBqxMCjHFMLa1tCAHoAKmRulAGhkaSuEiKS6HLkACIKcn2qklqFOkZWaGQAH2QGDwgYUAh3VvuC0m3Svf2eKAnTbIc50IQiECiO4PJ4vEBvD4EYE-XbaOj-ODSIGSUFSRTKEDQx7uZ6vd6ENTIeazTSgRqmZAAFT0EH8AFk4LokZJwWIwcIxAAaYFXNhQS7MMXCyQsYCiOl0WXy8DS0gCbSscgXQQa+QKVUkeRagmK-EqA0wklwt50Ymk+HuC3kFgAKwgCDAdGdbo90MYCgUwJgjw9wHIIDoADEQ2AwyAKZpgyBQ+HkAALOACNLFXQAeRgzP0dmBuacrggHi83vdYAtjhcbk8EW0-mQuYtjLLja8vhbAULrJgHN0cQAFMDJN66O3m3QzIKliy6IzgQBKL2uzJeABK7vIUHcDgXA-ZnJSjJyCQAZMDR6WGxWmyptMgqEyWafdOecl3H15cx0P5vqWlwQNUNygeBUCrtypBQBAYAMFAhLLK23opL2P6hNhi76OoiYxnGyBMOQ7jADA2i5q6NYYJATDjpO1Eeoy5BsqR5FomMMSmBavY2NqDQTEgUz8XYvatoJITxIQMFfCQCDhkIyDkAwYC6KpozJAAdDp1bMax7EUW0pyZAEo4ZlmOb5gOo58bYC77Oc+wObykL7KuskTqQKlqapGGWPxWkomU2hYc2gXnOwyCzLMyneHA2jApSEAKAIKDkcg5mZtmJTWSytkBfZBxOQ5orQO5nmSJOqnqWA-nTAoQU5qiYV2Y1kXRbF5DxYlkgaJI8GIchyk1ap+GEEAA)